# WordPress difficulty enqueueing accordion script

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm a newbie to "WordPress and I'm having problems enqueueing a script.  my script is called accordion (It's the one from http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp)
the file is called accordion.js 
I've placed it in the twentyseventeen/assets/js folder

and I tried to enqueue it by typing this(below) into my functions.php file.

```
function accordion() {  wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array( 'reset' ) );  wp_enqueue_style( 'reset',

get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/reset.css' ) );

wp_enqueue_script( 'accordion', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/accordion.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

wp_enqueue_script( 'theme-scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/website-scripts.js', array( 'accordion', 'jquery' ), '1.0', true ); }
```

This doesn't work, so I did something wrong (and silly), but I don't know what.

Could someone tell me what I did wrong and maybe point me in the right direction?

Marcel

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what is the result. Can you see the scripts/style sheet in your code when you inspect the source? You are looking for script/js files in your stylesheet directory, is this an error or are your scripts located in that directory?

Comment: Thanks Julian.  So, I don't see the function loading when I check the source.  Re: looking for the script/js in my stylesheet directory.  Yes.  That was an error.  I hadn't yet made a child theme (as I'm using this instance of WordPress as a test site).  Now I've made a child theme and moved the function into the child theme folder.  Still no luck though.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that the .js script is in the assets/js folder of the theme, but it looks like you are referencing it in the root of the theme folder:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'accordion', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/accordion.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
```

Instead of:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'accordion', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/accordion.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
```

Check this same thing for your other scripts & stylesheets in the function.

Also, where are you actually calling the accordian() function? Make sure you are actually calling it from somewhere in the head of the template.

Comment: Thanks Dave.  I see that my mistake was partially due to the fact wasn't using a child theme, so I fixed that (child theme of twentyseventeen) and then I made the edits (listed above) in the functions.php.  When I check the console, I see that accordion.js is not loading.  Have you got any other suggestions of what/where I might check?  Also, are you saying I should be editing the header-head.php file instead of functions.php?